# SharedSizeGroup в Grid в случае Width=Star

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть такой код из вложенных таблиц

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Beige" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Aquamarine" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="group2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="text1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="text2"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="group2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="text1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="text2sdf sd fsd fsd fsdaf"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Для наглядности добавил раскраску (закрашенные прямоугольники под низ).
Проблема вот в чем. Если вы добавите этот код на форму, увидите, что правые столбцы имеют одинаковый (как и задумано) размер, но не растянуты по величине таблицы, как задумывалось, а имеют размер максимального содержимого. Запускаем форму, тянем за сплиттер и видим, что размер столбцов, как и задумано, остается равным, но их положение относительно друг друга меняется. Мне же нужно, чтобы ширина столбцов была не по величине содержимого, а растянута до конца грида. Как это осуществить?

Уточнение:

Как я себе вижу результат. Правый столбец верхнего грида растянут до конца таблицы. Правый столбец нижнего грида выравнен по размеру правого столбца верхнего грида, а левый столбец нижнего грида должен за счет этого получиться меньше левого столбца верхнего грида на размер отступа. (в код добавил отступ)

Answer (score 3):

Обратимся к документации по [DefinitionBase.SharedSizeGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx):

> Columns and rows that participate in size-sharing do not respect `Star` sizing. In the size-sharing scenario, `Star` sizing is treated as `Auto`.

В переводе с басурманского это означает, что при использовании `SharedSizeGroup` растягивание колонок согласно размеру `*` не поддерживается. И вообще, сплиттер меняет размер колонки слева, а не справа, поэтому расшаривание размера имеет смысл только для левой колонки.

Соответственно, требуемое вами поведение невозможно реализовать с помощью `SharedSizeGroup`. Пишите код вручную.

Вот вариант реализации. Дадим имена колонкам, ширина которых должна равняться (с учётом маргина).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCoords.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="300" Height="300">
    <UniformGrid Rows="2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Beige">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="c11"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="text1"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="text2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Aquamarine" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="c21"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="text1"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="text2sdf sd fsd fsd fsdaf"/>
        </Grid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

После загрузки окна выровняем колонки, а затем подпишемся на изменения ширины, чтобы менять ширину другой колонки. Все действия откладываем до момента, когда контролы перерисованы, чтобы не вмешиваться в процесс.

```
partial class MainWindow
{
    private const double LeftMargin = 10;

    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {

            // Align widths after loading
            double maxWidth = Math.Max(c11.ActualWidth, c21.ActualWidth);
            c11.Width = new GridLength(maxWidth + LeftMargin);
            c21.Width = new GridLength(maxWidth);

            // Update width when width of another changes
            var propWidth = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
                ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, typeof(ColumnDefinition));
            propWidth.AddValueChanged(c11, (s, a) =>
                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    c21.Width = new GridLength(c11.ActualWidth - LeftMargin),
                    DispatcherPriority.Loaded));
            propWidth.AddValueChanged(c21, (s, a) =>
                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    c11.Width = new GridLength(c21.ActualWidth + LeftMargin),
                    DispatcherPriority.Loaded));

        }, DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    }
}
```

Обработка граничных случаев и исключений остаётся домашним заданием.

Comment: А почему `InvokeAsync`, а не привычный BeginInvoke? Или ещё более привычный `Loaded +=`?

Comment: 1. Потому что `InvokeAsync(Action)`, а `BeginInvoke(Delegate)`, со всеми вытекающими. 2. Потому что будет вызван один раз и без мусора `(sender, args)`.

Comment: А если я не знаю сколько будет строк + строки будут вложены друг в друга?

Comment: @iRumba Вычислять. Как получать координаты и размеры элементов, а также подписываться на изменения оных, вы знаете. Если есть желание, можете и свою панель написать.